# JDBC Query excecution

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, resultset

I am facing an issue while executing queries.I use the same resultSet and statement for excecuting all the queries.Now I face an intermittent SQlException saying that connection is already closed.Now we have to either have separate resultSet for each query or have lock like structure.Can anyone tell which is better.I think introducing locks will slow down the process.Am I right?

Update:
To be more clear.The error may happen because the finally block gets called before all the queries get executed and the connection gets closed and exception will be thrown.

This is the exception I get

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection has
>   already been closed.  at
>   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:81)
>     at
>   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:68)
>     at
>   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_com_informix_jdbc_IfxResultSet.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.test.test.execute(test.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:413)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:459)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl$ServletInvocationAction.run(ServletStubImpl.java:1077)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:465)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:7047)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:3902)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestImpl.java:2773)
>     at
>   weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
>     at
>   weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)

Sample code:

```
ResultSet rst=null; 
Statement stmt=null; 
Connection con=DBConnection.getConnection();
 stmt=con.createStatement();
 rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from dual");
 while(rst.next())
 { : ://Some code } 
rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from doctor where degree="BM");
 while(rst.next())
 { //blah blah } 
finally
 { 
//close con,rst and stmt 
}
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is somewhere in the code that you don't show us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not reusing the resultset, you are leaking resultsets.
rst=stmt.executeQuery... generates a new resultset and the previous resultset is never closed :(

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the code in question has issues in multi-threaded environment.

DBConnection.getConnection() is probably returning the same connection to all threads. When multiple threads are processing multiple requests, the first thread that finishes execution of the method will close the connection, leaving all other threads high and sundry.

I'm speculating here, but is appears that the connection object returned by DBConnection is an instance member of the DBConnection object, and that would qualify as a bad practice for a connection manager in a multi-threaded environment.

A code fix would avoid the usage of instance members for Connection, Statement (and the like), and the ResultSet objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on without knowing more about your code. Is it threaded ? Is the underlying database going down (or are you losing connectivity to it).

One thing I would do is to implement connection pooling (via [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/), say). This framework will maintain a pool of connections to your database and *validate* these connections before handing them out to you. You would ask for a new connection each time you make a query (or perhaps set of queries) but because they're pooled this shouldn't be a major oeverhead.

Comment: No its not threaded.I am using a single connection,resultset and statement.I am using the same statement and resultset for every query

Comment: How can you use the same resultset ? You mean that you're using the same code for every query and instantiating a new result set each time ? I think an example would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your connection to the database has really been closed I think you did something more like this:

```
try {
    return resultSet.getBoolean("SUCCESS");
} finally {
    resultSet.close();
}
```

This code will actually close the connection before your result set is being evaluated, resulting in the exception you show.

Comment: No, that can't be right. The finally clause is indeed executed before the method returns, but not before the return statement is _evaluated_.